# Python in ArcGis, cannot find what is wrong with my syntax

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am using Feature class to Feature class to batch convert some .dwg files. However python does not like the last statement (name).

[image]

It's probably something very simple, any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You may want to post some code; it's very difficult to read it in that image.
Also, you may want to use CAD to Geodatabase, not Feature Class to Feature Class, since a .dwg isn't a feature class.

Comment: Provide your code please!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's having a problem with the output directory, which is including a trailing slash: `"C:\TEST\MIDLANDS\ZIP\CONVERSION\SHP\"`

Try taking that off and see if it works: `"C:\TEST\MIDLANDS\ZIP\CONVERSION\SHP"`

---

You could also put this into a list/loop to simplify the syntax a little bit.

```
SiteList = ["1AMBLABLSITE001", "1BODDBODDSITE001", etc.]

for Site in SiteList:
    original = r"C:\TEST\MIDLANDS\ZIP\CONVERSION\{}.dwg\Polyline".format(Site)
    outputDir = r"C:\TEST\MIDLANDS\ZIP\CONVERSION\SHP\"
    outputName = Site
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(original, outputDir, outputName)
```